# Using GraphQL schema directive on a mutation input type

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I want to make use of a schema directive on a input type field. The directive defines a mapping, so in the mutation resolver I know which data to update.

For example:

```
input GeneralPropertiesInput {
  name: String @property(mapTo: "display.name")
  description: String @property(mapTo: "display.desc")
}

type Mutation {
  updateGeneralProperties(input: GeneralPropertiesInput): GeneralProperties
}
```

Is there an easy way to get the `property` directive for the input fields to update?

Comment: Not sure if this is a good solution but it works. I'm using the `info` object of the mutation resolver to traverse the input data AST and get the corresponding types with directives from the schema AST.